# .animate opacity: show - need display:block; instead of display:inline;

Tags: jquery

I want to show a certain element (em) on link hover.

I came up with this (through online tutorials).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $("ul.slidebtns li a").hover(function() {
        $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "show"}, "fast");
    }, function() {
        $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "fast");
    });
});
</script>
```

But .animate({opacity: "show"} gives me display:inline instead of display:block - as I've read around display:block should be a default behavior... so what is wrong?

Comment: `em` is not a block element by default, so it looks ok

Comment: how can I force block on em? with animate?

Comment: If your <ems> look fine BEFORE the effect, there's no good reason to change them to being block. Inline is already what you want! Otherwise, as per gdoron's answer you should style these particular ems as block within your CSS.

Comment: @Greg, the items don't look *anything* before the effect, since they're hidden (`display: none;`). Otherwise, it would make little sense to perform a fade-in animation on them.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Not what I meant, but I can see how I was being unclear. The point is, "if block is what you want, use CSS for that part of it."

Comment: @Greg, I see, we're in agreement then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can give it css in your `.css` file or in your jQuery code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("ul.slidebtns li a").hover(function() {
        $(this).next("em").css({ display: "block", opacity: 0 }).animate({ opacity: "show" }, "fast");
    }, function() {
        $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: @gdoron, there might be an issue with that code (off the top of my head, as I did not test it): since you're setting the `display` property to `block`, the element will become visible as a side-effect, so `animate()` will be left with nothing to animate, thus breaking the fade-in animation. `$(this).next("em").css({ display: "block", opacity: 0 }).animate({ opacity: "show" }, "fast");` might be more robust.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi. Changed to your's suggestion. Though I could think of a better solution (like a callback that will change the display to block) but he allready accepted an answer, and using a code to change css is really the second choice.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi. O.K. Now he changed the accepted answer to mine... =)

Comment: @gdoron, heh :) In passing, I don't think you want to set `display` to `block` in the animation's `complete` callback, as the fade-in will be complete and the element will be visible by then, so the abrupt layout switch will be noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

`display:block` is the default for the `fade` functions, `animate` doesn't default to anything as far as I know. What styles are on your elements?  It could be you've defined them to use inline display.

EDIT

What happens when you use the following CSS rule?

```
em {display: block;}
```

or more accurate (it that's your structure): `ul.slidebtns li a em {display:block;}`?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `animate({opacity: "show"}, "fast");` use `animate({height: "show",
width: "show"});`. Hope this helps.